# How to pass value from pom.xml to enabled attribute of test tag in testng

Tags: java, maven, selenium, testng, pom.xml

We can pass value to parameter tag like below but how can pass value to enabled attribute of test tag in testNG or is there any other way to pass value at runtime.

testNg.xml

```
    <test name="MavenProjectTest" enabled="true">
        <parameter name="value" value="${testcase}" />
        <parameter name="turl" value="${url}" />
        <classes>
            <class name="com.google.test.HomeTest">
                <methods>
                    <include name="TC1"></include>
                </methods>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

pom.xml

```
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.homeTestNg.path>src/resorces/java/homeTestNg.xml</project.homeTestNg.path>
        <tc.name>TC1</tc.name>
    </properties>       
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <systemPropertyVariables>
                            <testcase>${tc.name}</testcase>
                            <!-- <url>${gurl}</url> -->
                        </systemPropertyVariables>
                        <suiteXmlFiles>
                            <suiteXmlFile>${project.homeTestNg.path}</suiteXmlFile>
                        </suiteXmlFiles>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
            <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
            </resources>
    </build>
```